# to rename multiples file in multiple folders using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to write a batch file such that,it has to select the files from various folders as per the date passed in and copy those files to destination and rename the file(ie.if filename is like abcd_yyyymmdd then it will rename as abcd)

Please find below my batch file,it copies all respective files from source to destination as per the date specified,but the renaming is not done.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET date="20150211"

SET AAH_PATH=D:\ABC\Data\IN\ABCD
COPY D:\ABC\Data\IN\ABCD\*_%date%.txt D:\ABC\Data\File\*.txt
SET FOLDER_PATH=D:\ABC\Data\File
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%a.txt"
popd

SET SIE_PATH=D:\ABC\Data\IN\SIE
COPY D:\ABC\Data\IN\SIE\*_%date%.txt D:\ABC\Data\NEWFILE\*.txt
SET SIE_DEST=D:\ABC\Data\NEWFILE
pushd %SIE_DEST%
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%a.txt"
popd

SET UB_ABF=D:\ABC\Data\IN\UB\ABF
COPY D:\ABC\Data\IN\UB\ABF\*_%date%.txt D:\ABC\Data\UB\*.txt


SET UB_BCL=D:\RBC\Data\IN\UB\BCL
COPY D:\RBC\Data\IN\UB\BCL\*_%date%.txt D:\ABC\Data\UB\*.txt

SET UB_DEST=D:\ABC\Data\UB
pushd %UB_DEST%
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%a.txt"
popd
```

Could someone help me fix this problem

Comment: place an echo-command before the lines with the for-statement. This way you can control if the lines are expanded as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Try add the file extension to the source path in each for /f ren loop...

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%%a_%%b.txt" "%%a.txt"
```